# How can I programmatically terminate a running process in the same script that started it?

Tags: java, python, bash, perl, raku

**How do I start processes from a script in a way that also allows me to terminate them?**

Basically, I can easily terminate the main script, but terminating the external processes that this main script starts has been the issue. I googled like crazy for Perl 6 solutions. I was just about to post my question and then thought I'd open the question up to solutions in other languages.

Starting external processes is easy with Perl 6:

```
my $proc = shell("possibly_long_running_command");
```

[`shell`](https://doc.perl6.org/routine/shell) returns a process object after the process finishes. So, I don't know how to programmatically find out the PID of the running process because the variable `$proc` isn't even created until the external process finishes. (side note: after it finishes, `$proc.pid` returns an undefined `Any`, so it doesn't tell me what PID it used to have.)

Here is some code demonstrating some of my attempts to create a "self destructing" script:

```
#!/bin/env perl6

say "PID of the main script: $*PID";

# limit run time of this script
Promise.in(10).then( {
    say "Took too long! Killing job with PID of $*PID";
    shell "kill $*PID"
} );

my $example = shell('echo "PID of bash command: $$"; sleep 20; echo "PID of bash command after sleeping is still $$"');

say "This line is never printed";
```

This results in the following output which kills the main script, but not the externally created process (see output after the word `Terminated`):

```sh
[prompt]$ ./self_destruct.pl6
PID of the main script: 30432
PID of bash command: 30436
Took too long! Killing job with PID of 30432
Terminated
[prompt]$ my PID after sleeping is still 30436
```

By the way, the PID of `sleep` was also different (i.e. `30437`) according to `top`.

I'm also not sure how to make this work with [`Proc::Async`](https://doc.perl6.org/type/Proc::Async). Unlike the result of `shell`, the asynchronous process object it creates doesn't have a `pid` method.

I was originally looking for a Perl 6 solution, but I'm open to solutions in Python, Perl 5, Java, or any language that interacts with the "shell" reasonably well.

Comment: @3kings I tagged it Java because I am willing to accept Java answers, even though my original thought was just Perl 6.

Comment: He wrote that he accepts solutions with other languages (like java).

Comment: So you want to kill the process during its execution?

Comment: @aleb2000 Yes. Basically, I want to be able to set a time limit on it.

Comment: And you couldnt find any reasonable solution on google ?

Comment: Use [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3). It gives you the pid of the child process, then you can later kill it if you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Perl 6, there seems to be the [Proc::Async](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Proc::Async) module

> Proc::Async allows you to run external commands asynchronously, capturing standard output and error handles, and optionally write to its standard input.

```
# command with arguments
my $proc = Proc::Async.new('echo', 'foo', 'bar');

# subscribe to new output from out and err handles:
$proc.stdout.tap(-> $v { print "Output: $v" });
$proc.stderr.tap(-> $v { print "Error:  $v" });

say "Starting...";
my $promise = $proc.start;

# wait for the external program to terminate
await $promise;
say "Done.";
```

Method kill:

```
kill(Proc::Async:D: $signal = "HUP")
```

> Sends a signal to the running program. The signal can be a signal name ("KILL" or "SIGKILL"), an integer (9) or an element of the Signal enum (Signal::SIGKILL).

An example on how to use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

say 'Start';
my $proc = Proc::Async.new('sleep', 10);

my $promise= $proc.start;
say 'Process started';
sleep 2;
$proc.kill;
await $promise;
say 'Process killed';
```

As you can see, `$proc` has a method to kill the process.

Comment: My actual external command (not shown here) had several subprocesses running. This takes care of those. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Neither Perl, Perl 6, nor Java, but `bash`:

```
 timeout 5 bash -c "echo hello; sleep 10; echo goodbye" &
```

Comment: This works great. The `sleep` process is killed at the specified timeout. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can create a process like this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Path\program.exe", "param1", "param2", "ecc...");
Process process = processBuilder.start(); // start the process

process.waitFor(timeLimit, timeUnit); // This causes the current thread to wait until the process has terminated or the specified time elapses

// when you want to kill the process
if(process.isAlive()) {
    process.destroy();
}
```

Or you can use `process.destroyForcibly();`, see the [Process documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) for more info.

To execute a bash command point to the bash executable and set the command as a parameter.

Comment: That's the kind of control I was thinking about. Thanks!